# ZonedDateTime stored in DB with different value then in code

Tags: java, postgresql, date, datetime

In my Java code i do next:

`.setModifiedDate(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC))`

In debugger i see next value: 2020-04-07T07:36:20.386321Z - it is true

But in Postgresql i see next value: 2020-04-07 03:36:20 - It is not in UTC.

Field modifided_date id db have timestamptz type.

How to save to DB the same value as in code?

Comment: Please post output using psql CLI for your table of  `\d <your table>` ,`show time zone` and `select modified_date from <your table> where ...` .

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-datetime.html says  "for timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone."